# Nodemailer fails to send attachments

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have tried all the solutions indicated by other similar questions, but none solved my case. Still I can't send attachment. The mail is sent, apparently with the attach, also appears at the client side with the attachment, but it is an empty file.
I tried the most simple example, from the doc, ...

```
attachments[ filename: 'text1.txt', content: 'hello world!']
```

and it does work!, but for files in the disk, that is: ....

```
attachments: [ filename: 'text3.txt', path: '/path/to/file.txt' ]
```

this does not work. Also I have to change `filename` to `fileName`  and `path` to `pathName`, otherwise it gives `ENOENT...not such file or directory..`. As I said, the mail is sent without error, but the attachment is an empty file. Any suggestions? the nodemailer is version v6.6.3

Comment: please add some proper formatting to your question and show the *actual* code you are using ...

Comment: when you use `fileName` and `pathName` they are ignored by the library, because they are not known. You cannot just randomly change property names, but **must** use the properties names *excactly* as they are given in the documentation. `ENOENT` means, that the path to the file you provide via `path` does not exist. Can you actually verify, that the file really exists? Also be aware if `path` does not contain an absolute path, the path is relative to the current work directory

Comment: And you didn't literally use `path: "/path/to/file.txt"`, did you?

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks for your attention. Let me do some comments:

Comment: 1. Despite the documentation indicates 'filename' and 'path', it have to be changed to 'fileName' and 'pathName' otherwise ENOENT is fired, no matter the name and the path are correct. 2. Obviously, I fill out the real absolute path to the file to be attach, something like 'home/ricardo/documents/file.txt',

Comment: 1) Well, of course if you use `fileName` and `filePath` the error is not fired, because those properties are just ignored ...  2) obviously you don't because if you used the correct path, the error wouldn't be fired. Because if you use something like `home/ricardo...` the path is RELATIVE to your current directory. So the CORRECT path would probably be `/home/ricardo/...` (notice the additional `/` at the beginning of the path ...)

Comment: Sorry, yes , you are rigth, the path is '/home/....', but same result, the file attached is an empty file.